# Understanding SCSS

Tags: css, sass

First, I want to mention that the icon fonts are not freely available ones. We actually purchased them.

I have a SCSS file that is making references to some icon fonts. I get most of it but not sure what the seemingly hexadecimal values mean.

```
$icomoon-font-path: "../fonts" !default;

$stream-check-1: "\e62f";
$stream-check-circle-1: "\e634";
```

I then seem to have CSS classes that reference these values:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'myicon';
    src:    url('#{$icomoon-font-path}/streamline.eot?l1dykt');
    src:    url('#{$icomoon-font-path}/streamline.eot?l1dykt#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('#{$icomoon-font-path}/streamline.ttf?l1dykt') format('truetype'),
        url('#{$icomoon-font-path}/streamline.woff?l1dykt') format('woff'),
        url('#{$icomoon-font-path}/streamline.svg?l1dykt#streamline') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

.myicon-check-1 {
    &:before {
        content: $stream-check-1;
    }
}
```

I think I get most of it. My question is where do I get those hexadecimal values e.g. e62f?

UPDATE:
I've located some json files that are zipped up in file that mentions icomoon. Would these json files be of any help in this case? They look like this:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is this the font you're looking at? http://www.streamlineicons.com/index.html

Comment: Yes, they're the ones but not sure how to get these values.

Comment: @Sam only if the font that you are using on your web page has representation for these fonts will they be displayed else it will show a default rectangular box

Comment: Almost have the answer - do you have the font also installed on your computer? Also, do you have a mac?

Comment: @Sam - if you have a Mac, then I believe I have your answer. If you're on windows, you'll just need to use another form of Font Viewer in order to find the information you need.

Comment: @RyanGreen I'm on a Windows machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the right solution here. It's an online font viewer and when I click on the font, it shows the assigned value.

```
Just drag and drop the font file and 
it shows you the fonts and their values.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/iegik/r4ckgdc0/

Answer (score 1):

`"\e62f"` is [CSS syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#characters) for what would be `&#xe62f;` in HTML: a character with hexadecimal code `e62f`. You can see the code-to-glyph mapping by inspecting your font file (the way to do this will differ based on what OS you are using).

Answer (score 0):

Those are utf-8 icons. You can check them [here](https://www.utf8icons.com/character/58927/UTF-8-character).
For further lookup, check [this](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/E000-F8FF).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I forgot to mention that these CSS classes end up producing icons that we'd purchased. In other words, they're not icons that are freely available. We had to purchase the license for them. I assume the designer guy -- who's no longer in the team -- converted them to fonts. Is it safe to assume that in this conversion, these values were assigned?

Comment: I would not be so sure. When you look up the second link in my answer, these icons are not rendered. So, I will suggest try and test it and yes they are not freely available.

Comment: Yes: if your designer converted icon files to a font, then he had to assign character mapping for that font. Thus, the "should-be" mapping of Unicode does not apply - he could assign a victory sign to the position normally occupied by the letter `A`, if that is what he wanted to do (and as was actually done by the creator of the famous Wingdings font).

Comment: @Amadan If I understand you correctly, the designer "arbitrarily" assigned these values. Is there a way to see all the icons that are in the font?

Answer (score 0):

That `e62f`is actually referring to the `utf-8` encoding of characters. The HTML takes that "code" and turns it into a letter depending on what encoding you have. Most American websites I know of are just the `utf-8`

In your case, your webfont has replaced some of the normal values in order to use their own version of it. However, you might not be able to find the exact list of what other codes there are in this font as it's an Icomoon font (it appears to be) - which allows people to make their own webfont.

---

**EDIT:**

So if you have the font downloaded and have a mac - open up your `Font Book` Application. From there, find your font and look at all the characters. Choose the character you are looking for and copy it.

Go to a tool like this website: http://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/

And paste your character into the green convert area.

The value that you are looking for will be in the css box! (Of course it will show up as a box on this site, but as soon as you use that code on a site where you have the font downloaded - you'll see it match what you saw in `Font Book`)

I was able to reproduce this with my own custom font - so I was able to make it work. This was a great question and helped me find a tool that I'm definitely going to book mark! Cheers!